# Inverse of a triangular matrix in a statistical problem

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, statistics, numerical-linear-algebra

Can any one give to me idea how to solve this problem?

Find the inverse of the triangular matrix T, where

$ T =\left[ \begin{array}{ccc}
I & J & J \\ 0 & I & J \\ 0 & 0 & I \end{array}\right] $

and each sub-matrix is of order K $\times$ K and J is a matrix with each element equal to $+1$?

This question is related to linear models

Thank you

Comment: Maybe [Neumann series](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Neumann_series) could help? See also here: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/98562/proof-of-neumann-lemma

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I suppose that $I$ denotes [identity matrix](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Identity_matrix).

The matrix $T$ can be rewritten as $T=I-A$ where
$$A=\begin{pmatrix}0&-J&-J\\0&0&-J&\\0&0&0\end{pmatrix}.$$

If you know about [Neumann series](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Neumann_series), then $S=I+A+A^2+A^3+\dots$ seems as a reasonable candidate for $T^{-1}$, assuming that this series converges.

In this case we have
$$A^2=\begin{pmatrix}0&0&J^2\\0&0&0\\0&0&0\end{pmatrix}$$ 
and $A^3=A^4=\dots=A^{3+k}=0$.
So the inverse should be
$$T^{-1}=I+A+A^2=\begin{pmatrix}I&-J&J^2-J\\0&I&-J&\\0&0&I\end{pmatrix}.$$

We can check, using [multiplication of block matrices](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Block_matrix#Block_matrix_multiplication), that for these two matrices we indeed get
$$\begin{pmatrix}I&J&J\\0&I&J&\\0&0&I\end{pmatrix}\cdot\begin{pmatrix}I&-J&J^2-J\\0&I&-J&\\0&0&I\end{pmatrix}=
\begin{pmatrix}I&0&0\\0&I&0\\0&0&I\end{pmatrix}.$$

(In fact, since in this case $A^3=0$, we do not need Neumann series, it suffices if we notice that $(I-A)(I+A+A^2)=I-A^3$.)

If $J$ is a $k\times k$ matrix where each element is equal to $1$, then the result can be slightly simplified using $J^2=kJ$.

Comment: J is a matrix with each element equal to +1 can you explain this part what mean is different what you get in the final result thank you

Comment: @leenaadam As I have written in my answer, if $J$ is the matrix you described, then $J^2=kJ$. So instead of $J^2-J$ you can write $(k-1)J$ (i.e., the matrix, in which each entry is equal to $(k-1)$).