# Banach Lemma misunderstanding?

Tags: matrices, numerical-methods, normed-spaces

*The Banach Lemma:* 
Let  $B$ be an  n x n matrix . If in some induced matrix norm $ \|B\| < 1$, then
$ I + B $ is invertible and
$\|(I + B)\|^{-1} ≤
\frac1{(1− \| B \|)}.$

**Question**: Consider the n by n tridiagonal matrix $T_n$ = $diag[1, 3, 1]$ .
For example,
$$T_4 =\pmatrix{3 & 1 & 0& 0\cr 1&3 &1& 0\cr 0&1 &3 &1\cr 0 & 0& 1& 3}
$$
Use *the Banach Lemma* to show that $T_n$ is invertible for all positive
integers n.

$$$$

^ *This* is an assignment question I have, but I don't understand how I am supposed to answer it if when, clearly, $\|T_4\|_\infty = \|T_4\|_1 = 5 $ which does not satisfy the condition since n is 4 (positive) and $ \|B\|$ should be $ < 1$.

Is there something that I don't understand correctly? The prof has given this assignment for a few years now, I am thinking it is highly improbable that there there is a mistake in the question.

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Hint: Write $T_4 = 3(I+B)$ for some $B$ with $\|B\| < 1$.

Comment: I know it as [Neumann lemma](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/98562/proof-of-neumann-lemma).

Comment: The hint makes me feel silly lol. Thanks guys! If you make it an answer I can upvote it Prahalad

Comment: ^ @PrahladVaidyanathan

Answer (score 0, accepted):

See hint of Prahlad Vaidyanathan.

*Wrote this to close this question.