# Proof (id - T)^-1 = Neumann Series

Tags: sequences-and-series, analysis

Hi I have to prove that (id-T)^-1 = Neumann Series
like in this picture (Source: Wikipedia)
[image: Neumann Seris]

I have no clue how to do that. Can you give me a hint?

Comment: See [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/98562/proof-of-neumann-lemma).

Comment: Thanks. I did already found this thread. But in my equation i have Id (either this is identity or unity matrix like in the link). In this case is Id and I the same?

Comment: ... Yes, they are two notations for the same thing.

Comment: ok. This helped me a lot. Thank you very much! :)