# Operator Norm Inequality Used in The proof of Neumann Series Theorem

Tags: functional-analysis

Somewhere in the [proof](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/98562/proof-of-neumann-lemma) presented for Neumann Series Theorem, the following inequality is implicitly assumed. 
$$||A^k|| \leq ||A||^k.$$
The $||.||$ denotes the [operator norm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Operator_norm). How can I prove this inequality? Any hint where to begin?

Comment: To start, Prove the lemma $||AB||\le ||A|| ||B||$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If $\|Ax|| \leq a\|x\|$ and $\|Bx|| \leq b\|x\|$ for all $x$ then $\|ABx\| \leq a\|Bx\| \leq ab\|x\|$. Hence $\|AB\| \leq \|A\|\|B\|$. Now use induction to show that $\|A^{k}\| \leq \|A\|^{k}$.

Answer (score 1):

In the proof it is assumed that $\|\cdot\|$ is a matrix norm which is induced by a vector norm. Hence the matrix norm $\|\cdot\|$ is submultiplicative:

$$\|AB\| \le \|A\| \cdot \|B\|.$$