# Prove that the inverse operator of (Id-M) is both bounded and has operator norm less than $\frac{1}{{1 - \gamma }}$

Tags: functional-analysis, inverse

Suppose Id denotes the identity operator defined by $Id(v)=v$ for all $v \in V$ where V is the normed vector space $V$. Let also $M$ denote the operator $M:V \to V$ satisfying $\left\| M \right\| \le \gamma $ for some $\gamma$ less than 1 and greater than zero. I want to show that if $(Id-M):V\to V $ is invertible, then the inverse operator $(Id-M)^{-1}$ is bounded and $\left\| {\left( {Id - M} \right)} \right\| \le \frac{1}{{1 - \gamma }}$.

My answer: The first part follows from the open mapping theorem. Given a bijection, it maps open sets to open sets. Using this I could prove the inverse does same and hence bounded. However, I could not prove the second part (the bound on its norm).

Comment: There are several typos in the question.

Comment: I think you mean $\|M\| \leq \gamma$ instead of $\|V\| \leq \gamma$ there.  See https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/98562/proof-of-neumann-lemma for a sketch of one proof.

Answer (score 1):

Hint: $Id+M+M^{2}+\cdots$ converges in operator norm. If we denote this sum by $T$ then $T(Id-M)=(Id-M)T=I$. So $\|(Id-M)^{-1}|| =\|T\| \leq \sum_n \|M^{n}\| \leq \sum_n \gamma ^{n}=\frac 1 {1-\gamma}$.

Comment: But my question was not for the infinite sum, but only for the operator Id-M. I can not see the relevance of your answer to my question.

Comment: @FethiBencherki  this answer is giving the inverse to $Id-M$ explicitly which then helps to solve the problem.  The infinite sum gives the inverse.

Comment: ohh, my bad, I got it now. Thanks.

Comment: but I do appreciate if the argument could be developed using just the fact that $Id-M$ is bounded, and using that somehow bounding the norm to $(Id-M)^2$

Comment: I don't know what you mean but $\|(Id-M)^{2}\|\leq \|Id -M\|^{2}$.